# Show that $x$ is algebraic over $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $x$ be an indeterminate over $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $F=\mathbb{Q}(7x^3/(5x-13))$. Note that $F \subseteq \mathbb{Q}(x)$. Show that $x$ is algebraic over $F$ by expressly giving a polynomial over $F$ that $x$ is a root of.

My main issue is understanding what is meant by $\mathbb{Q}(7x^3/(5x-13))$ and how to find potential polynomials.

Comment: So, what did you try? Where do you get stuck at?

Comment: Just realized that I was missing that and I added it to my question.

Comment: $\Bbb Q(7x^3/(5x-13))$ is the field of rational functions in a variable $u$ over $\Bbb Q$. It just so happens that we have $u = \frac{7x^3}{5x-13}$, which means that your field is a _subfield_ of $\Bbb Q(x)$, the field of rational functions in the variable $x$. You're asked to show that this relation between the fields is that one is an algebraic extension of the other. In this case, that means you need to find some polynomial (in the variable $t$, say) where the _coefficients_ are rational functions in the ariable $u$ and $t = x$ is a solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\mathbf Q\Bigl(\dfrac{7x^3}{5x-13}\Bigr)$ simply denotes the set of rational functions in $u=\dfrac{7x^3}{5x-13}$. What else?

As to a polynomial equation satisfied by $x$ over $\mathbf Q(u)$, it's pretty simple:
$$u=\frac{7x^3}{5x-13}\iff 7x^3=u(5x-13)\iff 7x^3-5ux+13u=0,$$

so $\;[\mathbf Q(x):\mathbf Q(u)]=3.$

Comment: That's the path I was starting to head down, but I wasn't sure that's what was exactly meant by $\mathbb{Q}(7x^3/(5x-13))$. Thank you for clarifying.